# What's the Use of a Susskind Hologram?

Tags: science-based, society, black-holes

[image]

(this question may need to go to sandbox for refining)

Leonard Susskind [proposed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DIl3Hfh9tY&t=253s) that the surface of a black hole might be kind-of recording device for everything falling into it. Where 3D of space + 1D of time become 4 dimensions of space, practically.

I'm trying to imagine a culture living on or near one of these things. They have some properties:

- They can enter or leave at will (no more effort than taking a flight).
- Modern life would necessarily be digital beings, made of information (unless I'm mistaken).
- Something outside the black hole makes "updates" possible to the information stored in the black hole.
- It may be possible, through some other interference property, to update points in x,y,z,t without changing it.
- A thousand or a few million years of history are available as real estate for living. So you can stack people in both time and space.
- Because x,y,z,t are actually all spacial dimensions, cause & effect is now optional
- You can travel instantly (in relative time) to another x,y,z,t point; although there may be a non-zero absolute cost to moving.
- Probably possible to completely overwrite data in a spot of x,y,z,t to dedicate it to some present-day purpose. But would bemoan the loss of "greenfield" history to paving it over with the present.

**What distinguishes a society living in, or in close proximity to, a Susskind hologram (assuming they exist)? Are there any benefits (over digital and physical real-estate) to living in one?**

Comment: Methinks one of the factors that you will have to come to grips with is the actual area in our spacetime of the surface. How big are you proposing that this black hole Susskind Hologram is?

Comment: the author is arguing that information do not simply disappear in the blackhole so he proposed that they are encoded onto the surface of a blackhole instead, I remembered somebody else went even further proposing hologram within a hologram to resolve Hawking's error.

Comment: Sorry, meant to include size as Sagittarius A* -ish

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you mind linking to Susskind's writings on this? Might be helpful to know a bit more. Is this just a reference to the [holographic principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle)?

Comment: It looks like the holographic principle is more about heat density. Let me find the videos, and I'll add them to the question.

Comment: https://youtu.be/2DIl3Hfh9tY

Comment: *"They can enter or leave at will ":* no, they cannot. The fundamental idea about black holes is that inside the event horizon the radial direction away from the black hole is time-like: nothing can get out because it would imply time travel. Once something, *anything*, has crossed the event horizon, the event horizon is in the past and the black hole is in the future. That is to say, if they can go some place and come back, then that place *is not* inside the event horizon of a black hole. It doesn't matter what technology they have, it doesn't matter how powerful their engines are.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Remember that SE's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer (this isn't a discussion forum). As written you're just fishing for information, which is impractical here. Please modify your question to explain how you will judge the one best answer.

Comment: The black hole surface is 2-dimentional, not 4-dimensional.

Comment: @JBH I tried simplifying the underlying question to I hope better fit the one best answer model. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: @Anixx, I know it's a long video, but get to 36:00 minutes on the video and you'll see Mr. Susskind proposes both.

Comment: Ooooh. I like that.  Much better.  Thanks!

Comment: If there's no timelike dimension, then there's no causation. If there's no causation, then you have the wormhole aliens from *Star Trek* DS9.

Comment: @Kevin, yes, that's how I figured it. Causation inside is only artifically induced by something outside writing to the event horizon.

Comment: That's where I get to "how is it any different than simulated life?" Might be it isn't.

Comment: @AlexP Technically there is nothing that we KNOW OF can do that.  This is not the same as to say that there is not anything in the universe that might be able to do it.  We already know that there are particles that are not effected by other fundamental forces such as electromagnetism, the strong force, and the weak force; so, why would it be impossible for particles to exist that are not effected by gravity?

Comment: @Nosajimiki-ReinstateMonica: In the kind of physical model where black holes exist, gravity is not a force, but rather a geometrical property of spacetime. In the kind of physical model where gravity is a force, black holes don't exist.

Comment: @alexP - there are two ideas I'm looking at that make me think it's plausible (if not hard) science : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmA1sOdzsYc&t=3s and what Mr. Susskind called the "Negative First Law of Thermo", that information can not be destroyed -- an idea that has stood up to some testing. https://phys.org/news/2011-03-quantum-no-hiding-theorem-experimentally.html

Comment: @Kevin Lack of a distinguished timelike dimension does not imply that there is no causation, merely that cause and effect do not have a universal invariant ordering.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley: If there's no invariant ordering, then it becomes difficult to coherently describe one event as the cause of another, given that different observers may see them in either order. Regardless, under relativity, it is impossible for spacelike-separated events to cause or interact with one another without superluminal (faster-than-light) communication, so you'd have to break that rule for this to make sense. Then you end up with a spacetime geometry very different from our own.

Comment: @Kevin Assignment of cause and effect become conventional rather than physically forced, but that doesn't make it difficult to do. And yes, you do indeed indeed end up with spacetime geometry very different from our own. Specifically, Reimannian geometry rather than Minkowski geometry.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley: Well, sure, you can stick whatever arbitrary labels you want on the diagram, but I'm doubtful that those labels are helpful in [describing or understanding the underlying reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map%E2%80%93territory_relation).

Comment: @Kevin If you have a conscious observer, a hyperplane perpendicular to their worldline separating past from future is very helpful in describing and understanding the underlying reality from their local point of view.

Comment: Agree with @AlexP, this entire question assumes that they traverse the event horizon of a black hole at will, which is just impossible. Entering the black hole is a one-way trip and you can't get back out. The black hole is not RAM, it is not a hard drive. It is essentially write-only-no-read memory.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas for consideration:

### Deterministic Social Sciences

A computer simulation is only as good as the model. Models try to fit data. However, the limitations of cost and time limit the resolution and volume of information we collect.

As a result, many fields that are incredible complex -- social science, and medicine as two examples depend on statistical strength to back up hypotheses.

But what if every detail, no matter how mundane, was meticulously recorded by an dispassionate event horizon? Study participants couldn't lie, or misunderstand the instructions. No confounding variables.

Assuming social and medical sciences aren't already "good enough" at this point, inside the hologram would be a great place for researches to try to find deterministic models that precisely explain social behavior.

This might be applicable to medicine as well.

### Deterministic Quantum Mechanics, Pilot Wave Theories

I have a feeling that really understanding these subjects would be a pre-requisite to being able to digitally enter or leave an event horizon. But in case they are not, this would be the perfect high-energy lab to study every event in super-slow-motion, and with as much detail as the event horizon can provide.

### White Holes, Fast Radio Bursts

It may be natural that black holes [sometimes emit energy](http://youtube.com/watch?v=GmA1sOdzsYc&t=3s). If this is true, it would probably be an enabling technology to enter and leave the event hologram. It would also be an important field of study, especially since these eruptions reduce the energy of the event horizon, reduce the area by ${\Delta E} \over A$, and reduce the information inside the hologram.

### Studying the Chemistry of the Singularity

Neutron stars may have cores of [quark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QCD_matter). It's also possible that the periodic table opens up to [stable exotic matter past 300 protons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continent_of_stability), which might be found in some large neutron stars, and possibly around the singularity. It may open up a whole new fields of chemistry, that a simulation could not begin to guess at.

There may be even more exotic things within the black hole itself.

### Studying Unification Theories

You might be able to get a better view of extremely high energies and how forces flow together inside the event horizon. A digital world will only be able to simulate the vantage points you can construct with your imagination.

### Non-Linear Fine Structure Constants

If the [fine structure constant does turn out to vary](https://io9.gizmodo.com/ask-a-physicist-is-the-fine-structure-constant-really-5642233), this is potentially a very good place to study it from. It might be possible to set-up labs with differing fine-structure constants, and study how physical laws change in these regimes. It might open up a new branch of engineering, tinkering with what we currently consider constants to achieve practical effects.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand Susskind's concept correctly, the source of the information recorded on the surface of the event horizon is light from the region surrounding the singularity. If this is the case, perhaps the event horizon would encapsulate a history of the region.  Distant objects and phenomena which existed far in the past could potentially be studied at resolutions not possible otherwise. This scenario would fit well with an advanced civilization devoted to archeological pursuit. A society of scholars able to occupy the singularity might decide to establish an Academy there. Perhaps a hyper advanced library similar to Isaac Asimov 's Foundation.